# AAC not playing in Safari

Tags: javascript, audio, safari

I am using audio files on browsers and I noticed that .aac works on Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer, but on Safari it just makes a single click noise and doesn't play anything.
Now I can use other formats that do work on Safari, but I would like to know if I am doing something wrong.

A search on caniuse shows that it should be supported on all current browsers.

I am playing the audio like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio/file.aac');
audio.play();
```

When I use `audio.canPlayType('audio/aac);` on Safari it returns `maybe`

Comment: How did you obtain / generate the AAC file? Perhaps there's an encoding issue on the specific file that only causes Safari to muck it up.

Comment: I am not 100% positive as I just received the sound file, and didn't think of that to be honest. I believe it was a WAV file exported to AAC in Adobe Audition. I can try having it exported again, maybe with different settings, when I have the chance. Thank you.